# PHP calling function of a non-object

Tags: php, session-variables

Im having problems with creating a session class - Im trying to pass the database object to it to call its functions however I keep getting the error call to undefined function at like 46 of ssession.class.php, OR, as weird as this sound, gives me a diffrent error that its called on a non-object.  I thought you could store objects as class variables and don't understand why its not finding database.

```
<?php

include("http://www.walkingspheres.com/include/database.class.php");
include("http://www.walkingspheres.com/include/mailer.php");
include("http://www.walkingspheres.com/include/form.php");

class Session
{
   var $username;     //Username given on sign-up
   var $sessionid;    //Random value generated on current login
   var $userlevel;    //The level to which the user pertains
   var $time;         //Time user was last active (page loaded)
   var $logged_in;    //True if user is logged in, false otherwise
   var $userinfo = array();  //The array holding all user info
   var $url;          //The page url current being viewed
   var $referrer;     //Last recorded site page viewed
   var $database;

   /* Class constructor */
   function Session($db){
      $this->time = time();
      $this->databse = $db;
      $this->startSession();
   }

   /**
    * startSession - Performs all the actions necessary to 
    * initialize this session object. Tries to determine if the
    * the user has logged in already, and sets the variables 
    * accordingly. Also takes advantage of this page load to
    * update the active visitors tables.
    */
   function startSession(){
      session_start();   //Tell PHP to start the session

      /* Determine if user is logged in */
      $this->logged_in = $this->checkLogin();

      /**
       * Set guest value to users not logged in, and update
       * active guests table accordingly.
       */
      if(!$this->logged_in){
         $this->username = $_SESSION['username'] = GUEST_NAME;
         $this->userlevel = GUEST_LEVEL;
         $this->database->addActiveGuest($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $this->time);
      }
      /* Update users last active timestam*/
      else{
         $this->database->addActiveUser($this->username, $this->time);
      }

      /* Remove inactive visitors from database */
      $this->database->removeInactiveUsers();
      $this->database->removeInactiveGuests();

      /* Set referrer page */
      if(isset($_SESSION['url'])){
         $this->referrer = $_SESSION['url'];
      }else{
         $this->referrer = "/";
      }

      /* Set current url */
      $this->url = $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
   }

   /**
    * checkLogin - Checks if the user has already previously
    * logged in, and a session with the user has already been
    * established. Also checks to see if user has been remembered.
    * If so, the database is queried to make sure of the user's 
    * authenticity. Returns true if the user has logged in.
    */
   function checkLogin(){  

            /* Check if user has been remembered */
      if(isset($_COOKIE['cookname']) && isset($_COOKIE['cookid'])){
         $this->username = $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['cookname'];
         $this->sessionid   = $_SESSION['sessionid']   = $_COOKIE['cookid'];
      }

      /* Username and sessionid have been set and not guest */
      if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['sessionid']) &&
         $_SESSION['username'] != GUEST_NAME){
         /* Confirm that username and sessionid are valid */
         if($this->database->confirmSessionID(
                    $_SESSION['username'],$_SESSION['sessionid'])!= 0)
         {
            /* Variables are incorrect, user not logged in */
            unset($_SESSION['username']);
            unset($_SESSION['sessionid']);
            return false;
         }

         /* User is logged in, set class variables */
         $this->userinfo  = $this->database->getUserInfo($_SESSION['username']);
         $this->username  = $this->userinfo['username'];
         $this->sessionid    = $this->userinfo['sessionid'];
         $this->userlevel = $this->userinfo['userlevel'];
         return true;
      }

      /* User not logged in */
      else{
         return false;
      }
   }

   /**
    * login - The user has submitted his username and password
    * through the login form, this function checks the authenticity
    * of that information in the database and creates the session.
    * Effectively logging in the user if all goes well.
    */
   function login($subuser, $subpass, $subremember){
      $form;  //The database and form object

      /* Username error checking */
      $field = "user";  //Use field name for username
      if(!$subuser || strlen($subuser = trim($subuser)) == 0){
         $form->setError($field, "* Username not entered");
      }
      else{
         /* Check if username is not alphanumeric */
         if(!preg_match("/^([0-9a-z])*$/", $subuser)){
            $form->setError($field, "* Username not alphanumeric");
         }
      }

      /* Password error checking */
      $field = "pass";  //Use field name for password
      if(!$subpass){
         $form->setError($field, "* Password not entered");
      }

      /* Return if form errors exist */
      if($form->num_errors > 0){
         return false;
      }

      /* Checks that username is in database and password is correct */
      $subuser = stripslashes($subuser);
      $result = $this->database->confirmUserPass($subuser, md5($subpass));

      /* Check error codes */
      if($result == 1){
         $field = "user";
         $form->setError($field, "* Username not found");
      }
      else if($result == 2){
         $field = "pass";
         $form->setError($field, "* Invalid password");
      }

      /* Return if form errors exist */
      if($form->num_errors > 0){
         return false;
      }

      /* Username and password correct, register session variables */
      $this->userinfo  = $this->database->getUserInfo($subuser);
      $this->username  = $_SESSION['username'] = $this->userinfo['username'];
      $this->sessionid    = $_SESSION['sessionid']   = $this->generateRandID();
      $this->userlevel = $this->userinfo['userlevel'];

      /* Insert sessionid into database and update active users table */
      $this->database->updateUserField($this->username, "sessionid", $this->sessionid);
      $this->database->addActiveUser($this->username, $this->time);
      $this->database->removeActiveGuest($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

      /**
       * This is the cool part: the user has requested that we remember that
       * he/she logged in, so we set two cookies. One to hold his/her username,
       * and one to hold his/her random value sessionid. It expires by the time
       * specified in definitions.php. Now, next time he/she comes to our site, we will
       * log him/her in automatically, but only if she/he didn't log out before they left
      */
      if($subremember){
         setcookie("cookname", $this->username, time()+COOKIE_EXPIRE, COOKIE_PATH);
         setcookie("cookid",   $this->sessionid,   time()+COOKIE_EXPIRE, COOKIE_PATH);
      }

      /* Login completed successfully */
      return true;
   }

   /**
    * logout - Gets called when the user wants to be logged out of the
    * website. It deletes any cookies that were stored on the users
    * computer as a result of him wanting to be remembered, and also
    * unsets session variables and demotes his user level to guest.
    */
   function logout(){
      /**
       * Delete cookies - the time must be in the past,
       * so just negate what you added when creating the
       * cookie.
       */
      if(isset($_COOKIE['cookname']) && isset($_COOKIE['cookid'])){
         setcookie("cookname", "", time()-COOKIE_EXPIRE, COOKIE_PATH);
         setcookie("cookid",   "", time()-COOKIE_EXPIRE, COOKIE_PATH);
      }

      /* Unset PHP session variables */
      unset($_SESSION['username']);
      unset($_SESSION['sessionid']);
      unset($_SESSION['error_array']);
      unset($_SESSION['value_array']);
      unset($_SESSION['regsuccess']);

      /* Reflect fact that user has logged out */
      $this->logged_in = false;

      /**
       * Remove from active users table and add to
       * active guests tables.
       */
      $this->database->removeActiveUser($this->username);
      $this->database->addActiveGuest($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $this->time);

      /* Set user level to guest */
      $this->username  = GUEST_NAME;
      $this->userlevel = GUEST_LEVEL;
   }

   /**
    * register - Gets called when the user has just submitted the
    * registration form. Determines if there were any errors with
    * the entry fields, if so, it records the errors and returns
    * 1. If no errors were found, it registers the new user and
    * returns 0. Returns 2 if registration failed.
    */

   function register($subuser,$subpass,$subemail,$c_pass,$c_email,$home,$bday){
      global $form, $mailer;  //The database, form and mailer object

      /* Username error checking */
      $field = "user";  //Use field name for username
      $subuser=trim($subuser);
      if(strlen($subuser) == 0){
         $form->setError($field, "* Username not entered");
      }
      else{
         /* Spruce up username, check length */
         $subuser = stripslashes($subuser);
         if(strlen($subuser) < 5){
            $form->setError($field, "* Username below 5 characters");
         }
         else if(strlen($subuser) > 30){
            $form->setError($field, "* Username above 30 characters");
         }
         /* Check if username is not alphanumeric */
         else if(!preg_match("/^([0-9a-z])+$/", $subuser)){
            $form->setError($field, "* Username not alphanumeric");
         }
         /* Check if username is reserved */
         else if(strcasecmp($subuser, GUEST_NAME) == 0){
            $form->setError($field, "* Username reserved word");
         }
         /* Check if username is already in use */
         else if($this->database->usernameTaken($subuser)){
            $form->setError($field, "* Username already in use");
         }
         /* Check if username is banned */
         else if($this->database->usernameBanned($subuser)){
            $form->setError($field, "* Username banned");
         }
      }

      /* Password error checking */
      $field = "password";  //Use field name for password
      $subpass=trim($subpass);
      $c_pass=trim($c_pass);
      if(strlen($subpass)==0 || strlen($c_pass)==0){
         $form->setError($field, "* Password not entered");
      }
      else{
         /* Spruce up password and check length*/
         if(strlen($subpass) < 4){
            $form->setError($field, "* Password too short");
         }
         /* Check if password is not alphanumeric */
         else if(!preg_match("/^([0-9a-z])+$/", $subpass)){
            $form->setError($field, "* Password not alphanumeric");
         }
         /* Check if both passwords entered match */
         else if(strcmp($subpass,$c_pass) != 0){
            $form->setError($field, "* Passwords don't match");
     }
      }

      /* Email error checking */
      $field = "email";  //Use field name for email
      $subemail=trim($subemail);
      $c_email=trim($c_email);
      if(strlen($subemail) == 0){
         $form->setError($field, "* Email not entered");
      }
      else{
         /* Check if valid email address */
         $regex = "/^[_+a-z0-9-]+(\.[_+a-z0-9-]+)*"
                 ."@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]{1,})*"
                 ."\.([a-z]{2,}){1}$/";
         if(!preg_match($regex,$subemail)){
            $form->setError($field, "* Email invalid");
         }
         else if(strcmp($subemail,$c_email)!=0){
           $form->setError($field, "* Emails don't match");
     }
      }

      /* Errors exist, have user correct them */
      if($form->num_errors > 0){
         return 1;
      }
      /* No errors, add the new account to the db */
      else{
        $home=trim($home);
        $bday=trim($bday);
         if($this->database->addNewUser($subuser, md5($subpass),$subemail,$home,$bday)){
            if(EMAIL_WELCOME){
               $mailer->sendWelcome($subuser,$subemail,$subpass);
            }
            return 0;  //New user added succesfully
         }else{
            return 2;  //Registration attempt failed
         }
      }
   }

   /**
    * editAccount - Attempts to edit the user's account information
    * including the password, which it first makes sure is correct
    * if entered, if so and the new password is in the right
    * format, the change is made. All other fields are changed
    * automatically.
    */
   function editAccount($subcurpass, $subnewpass, $subemail){
      global $form;  //The database and form object
      /* New password entered */
      if($subnewpass){
         /* Current Password error checking */
         $field = "curpass";  //Use field name for current password
         if(!$subcurpass){
            $form->setError($field, "* Current Password not entered");
         }
         else{
            /* Check if password too short or is not alphanumeric */
            $subcurpass = stripslashes($subcurpass);
            if(strlen($subcurpass) < 4 ||
               !preg_match("/^([0-9a-z])+$/", ($subcurpass = trim($subcurpass)))){
               $form->setError($field, "* Current Password incorrect");
            }
            /* Password entered is incorrect */
            if($this->database->confirmUserPass($this->username,md5($subcurpass)) != 0){
               $form->setError($field, "* Current Password incorrect");
            }
         }

         /* New Password error checking */
         $field = "newpass";  //Use field name for new password
         /* Spruce up password and check length*/
         $subpass = stripslashes($subnewpass);
         if(strlen($subnewpass) < 4){
            $form->setError($field, "* New Password too short");
         }
         /* Check if password is not alphanumeric */
         else if(!preg_match("/^([0-9a-z])+$/", ($subnewpass = trim($subnewpass)))){
            $form->setError($field, "* New Password not alphanumeric");
         }
      }
      /* Change password attempted */
      else if($subcurpass){
         /* New Password error reporting */
         $field = "newpass";  //Use field name for new password
         $form->setError($field, "* New Password not entered");
      }

      /* Email error checking */
      $field = "email";  //Use field name for email
      if($subemail && strlen($subemail = trim($subemail)) > 0){
         /* Check if valid email address */
         $regex = "/^[_+a-z0-9-]+(\.[_+a-z0-9-]+)*"
                 ."@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]{1,})*"
                 ."\.([a-z]{2,}){1}$/";
         if(!preg_match($regex,$subemail)){
            $form->setError($field, "* Email invalid");
         }
         $subemail = stripslashes($subemail);
      }

      /* Errors exist, have user correct them */
      if($form->num_errors > 0){
         return false;  //Errors with form
      }

      /* Update password since there were no errors */
      if($subcurpass && $subnewpass){
         $this->database->updateUserField($this->username,"password",md5($subnewpass));
      }

      /* Change Email */
      if($subemail){
         $this->database->updateUserField($this->username,"email",$subemail);
      }

      /* Success! */
      return true;
   }

   /**
    * isAdmin - Returns true if currently logged in user is
    * an administrator, false otherwise.
    */
   function isAdmin(){
      return ($this->userlevel == ADMIN_LEVEL ||
              $this->username  == ADMIN_NAME);
   }

   /**
     * confirmFriends - pre: sessionid, requestingid
     * returns true if they are both friends
     * else returns false
     */
   function confirmFriends($uid,$rid){
     $q = "SELECT name FROM friends WHERE userid_fk='$uid' AND fid='$rid' ";
     $res->$this->database->query($q);
     if($res){  //exists
       return true;
     }
     else
       return false;
   } 

   /**
    * generateRandID - Generates a string made up of randomized
    * letters (lower and upper case) and digits and returns
    * the md5 hash of it to be used as a sessionid.
    */
   function generateRandID(){
      return md5($this->generateRandStr(16));
   }

   /**
    * generateRandStr - Generates a string made up of randomized
    * letters (lower and upper case) and digits, the length
    * is a specified parameter.
    */
   function generateRandStr($length){
      $randstr = "";
      for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){
         $randnum = mt_rand(0,61);
         if($randnum < 10){
            $randstr .= chr($randnum+48);
         }else if($randnum < 36){
            $randstr .= chr($randnum+55);
         }else{
            $randstr .= chr($randnum+61);
         }
      }
      return $randstr;
   }
}

/**
 * Initialize session object - This must be initialized before
 * the form object because the form uses session variables,
 * which cannot be accessed unless the session has started.
 */

$session = new Session($database);

/* Initialize form object */
$form = new Form();
?>
```

My other problem, and below you'll see the database class, but I have session_start(); at the top of all my pages and for some reason the mix between database and session refuse to actually register or login anyone.  Maybe someone could identify a reason why?

```
<?php

require_once("http://www.walkingspheres.com/definitions.php");

class MySQLDB
{
   var $connection;         //The MySQL database connection
   var $num_active_users;   //Number of active users viewing site
   var $num_active_guests;  //Number of active guests viewing site
   var $num_members;        //Number of signed-up users
   /* Note: call getNumMembers() to access $num_members! */

   /* Class constructor */
   function MySQLDB(){
      /* Make connection to database */
      $this->connection = mysql_connect("localhost","name","pass") or die(mysql_error());
      mysql_select_db("pen15_users", $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());

      /**
       * Only query database to find out number of members
       * when getNumMembers() is called for the first time,
       * until then, default value set.
       */
      $this->num_members = -1;

      if(TRACK_VISITORS){
         /* Calculate number of users at site */
         $this->calcNumActiveUsers();

         /* Calculate number of guests at site */
         $this->calcNumActiveGuests();
      }
   }

   /**
    * confirmUserPass - Checks whether or not the given
    * username is in the database, if so it checks if the
    * given password is the same password in the database
    * for that user. If the user doesn't exist or if the
    * passwords don't match up, it returns an error code
    * (1 or 2). On success it returns 0.
    */
   function confirmUserPass($username, $password){
      /* Verify that user is in database */
      $q = "SELECT password FROM members WHERE username = '$username'";
      $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
      if(!$result || (mysql_numrows($result) < 1)){
         return 1; //Indicates username failure
      }

      /* Retrieve password from result, strip slashes */
      $dbarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      $dbarray['password'] = stripslashes($dbarray['password']);
      $password = stripslashes($password);

      /* Validate that password is correct */
      if($password == $dbarray['password']){
         return 0; //Success! Username and password confirmed
      }
      else{
         return 2; //Indicates password failure
      }
   }

   /**
    * confirmSessionID - Checks whether or not the given
    * username is in the database, if so it checks if the
    * given userid is the same userid in the database
    * for that user. If the user doesn't exist or if the
    * userids don't match up, it returns an error code
    * (1 or 2). On success it returns 0.
    */
  public function confirmSessionId($username, $sessionid){
      /* Add slashes if necessary (for query) */
      if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
          $username = addslashes($username);
      }

      /* Verify that user is in database */
      $q = "SELECT sessionid FROM members WHERE username = '$username'";
      $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
      if(!$result || (mysql_numrows($result) < 1)){
         return 1; //Indicates username failure
      }

      /* Retrieve id from result, strip slashes */
      $dbarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);

      /* Validate that sessionid is correct */
      if($sessionid == $dbarray['sessionid']){
         return 0; //Success! Username and session confirmed
      }
      else{
         return 2; //Indicates userid invalid
      }
   }

   /**
    * usernameTaken - Returns true if the username has
    * been taken by another user, false otherwise.
    */
   function usernameTaken($username){
      $q = "SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = '$username'";
      $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
      return (mysql_numrows($result) > 0);
   }

   /**
    * usernameBanned - Returns true if the username has
    * been banned by the administrator.
    */
   function usernameBanned($username){
      if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
         $username = addslashes($username);
      }
      $q = "SELECT username FROM banned_users WHERE username = '$username'";
      $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
      return (mysql_numrows($result) > 0);
   }

   /**
    * addNewUser - Inserts the given (username, password, email)
    * info into the database. Appropriate user level is set.
    * Returns true on success, false otherwise.
    */
   function addNewUser($username,$password,$email,$home,$bday){
      $time = time();
      /* If admin sign up, give admin user level */
      if(strcasecmp($username, 'pen15') == 0 ||
         strcasecmp($username, 'Charlie DeHart')==0 ){
         $ulevel = 9;
      }else{
         $ulevel = 1;
      }
      $home=trim($home);
      $bday=trim($day);
      if($home='' || $home=NULL)
        $home = 'default';

      if($bday='' || $bday=NULL)
        $bday = 'default';

      $sessionid = '1'; 

      $q = "INSERT INTO members(username, password,";
            "email, userlevel, timestamp, home, birthday, sessionid) ";
            "VALUES ('$username','$password','$email','$ulevel','$time',";
            "'$home','$bday','$sessionid')";

      return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
   }

   /**
    * updateUserField - Updates a field, specified by the field
    * parameter, in the user's row of the database.
    */
   function updateUserField($username, $field, $value){
    $q = "UPDATE members SET ".$field." = '$value' WHERE username = '$username'";
      return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
   }

   /**
    * getUserInfo - Returns the result array from a mysql
    * query asking for all information stored regarding
    * the given username. If query fails, NULL is returned.
    */
   function getUserInfo($username){
      $q = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$username'";
      $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
      /* Error occurred, return given name by default */
      if(!$result || (mysql_numrows($result) < 1)){
         return NULL;
      }
      /* Return result array */
      $dbarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      return $dbarray;
   }

}

/* Create database connection */
$database = new MySQLDB;

?>
```

Thank you very much for any comments, help, or an explanation as to if including a file wich creates a new class at the bottom will call the constructor.

Comment: You should attempt to isolate the problem further, as you are more likely to get help if you can post a code-snippet instead of entire classes.

Comment: post more code, and the manual to your toaster :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Your code is quite long, and I've not tried to understand it all -- but I've seen one thing that feels odd)*

You `MySQLDB` class has its `$connection` property that is a [**`resource`**][1] -- as its obtained as the return value of the [**`mysql_connect()`**][2] function.

Resources cannot be serialized -- see the manual page of [**`serialize()`**][3] for a reference *(quoting)* :

> `serialize()` handles all types, **except
> the resource-type**.

I'm guessing the `$database` property of your `Session` class points to an instance of your `MYSQLDB` class -- which contains a resource.

That resource cannot be serialized -- so, it cannot be stored in `$_SESSION` ; or, more specifically, it cannot be restored from session.

To address this specific point, you should re-connect to your database when the session is loaded -- the [`__sleep()` and `__wakeup()`][4] magic methods might help, here.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $this->databse = $db;
```

It should be $this->database

Gotta hate typos eh? Since the assigning of the object property is not being done right, $this->database is null and thus the function (more a method in this case) you're trying to call is undefined.

On another note (since the comment above should fix your current problem): You're exposing yourself to death.

```
function confirmUserPass($username, $password){
  /* Verify that user is in database */
  $q = "SELECT password FROM members WHERE username = '$username'";
  $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
```

What if I make $username be something that does some SQL that you do not desire? It wouldn't be hard. Please either use mysql_escape_string (eh, I might be wrong about the exact name of the function, I always work with PDO nowadays) or change your code to prepared statements. Else you will be suffering from SQL injection (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Do the same for EVERY single data entry to the DB that was originally submitted by the user (and often even if it was indirectly submitted by a user)

Answer (score 1):

```
include("http://www.walkingspheres.com/include/database.class.php");
include("http://www.walkingspheres.com/include/mailer.php");
include("http://www.walkingspheres.com/include/form.php");
```

## Yikes!

Wow, do you have `allow_url_fopen` enabled?  It looks like it.  That or you have your error reporting level turned way, way down.  If these lines of code are working, [then your code is exploiting an incorrect PHP setting that may be a **huge** security hole](http://blog.php-security.org/archives/45-PHP-5.2.0-and-allow_url_include.html).

`include` **executes code**.  You're `include`-ing URLs.  This means that PHP is *making web requests* to download those files.  If someone were able to trick your code into performing an arbitrary `include`, they could execute *their* code on your server, and you'd never know.

Those are PHP scripts.  It's very likely that they're being executed when the request is made instead of returning the source code, and are instead returning nothing.  That or PHP *is* properly configured, but that your error reporting level is hiding the problem.

Please change all of those `include`, `include_once`, `require` and `require_once` calls to use **paths on the filesystem** instead of URLs.

Also **turn up your error reporting level** during development using the following two lines of code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(-1);
```

I'm willing to bet that turning up the error reporting is going to make PHP whine *incredibly loudly* about the problems you're having, from the serialization issues to the database typo.

Also, could you tell us where you picked up that "Session" class?  It's really, really old and people constantly have trouble with it.  It's poorly designed and probably should not be used in the modern age.  I'd really like to know where it comes from so I can have the author -- *ahem* -- *re-educated* and/or have datacenter hosting it nuked from orbit.

Comment: Thank you, and I guess with this amount of comments im just going to write a new session class.  Any recommendations about class variables/functions?  I need to make a social network within 14 days and im feeling a bit overwhelmed.

Comment: Thanks for that link, Tony.  You might want to consider avoiding any PHP tutorials or guides written before 2008 or so.  Also, assuming that this isn't a homework assignment, you might want to seriously consider just grabbing an existing PHP social networking package like SocialEngine or Elgg (neither of which I can vouch for other than knowing that they exist), and spending your time customizing it to your needs.  Social networking is *very difficult* to get right.

Comment: With regards to a session "class"... don't.  That's seriously over-complicating things.  Logging in and logging out is not a hard thing.  It's *user management* that's more sticky.  Consider [building on top of PEAR's LiveUser](http://pear.php.net/package/LiveUser).  It's a slight bit clunky, but it's modern and maintained.